# pandas read_csv error on windows

Tags: python, parsing, pandas

I am trying to read a file 57MB with `pandas.csv_read`. The file contains a header (5 rows), afterwads integer values and at the end float values:

```
info         
       2681087         53329       1287215       1287215         53328
RSA                    53328         53328       1287215             0
(I14)           (I14)           (d25.15)            (d25.15)            
F                          1         5332   
           1
          33
          61
          92
         128
         ...
         165
         205
         239
         272
    0.112474585277959E+09
    0.126110931411177E+09
    0.515995872032845E+09
    0.126110931411175E+09
   -0.194634413074014E+09
    0.112474585277950E+09
    ...
```

When I read the txt file:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=5+n_int_values, header=None, engine='c', 
            dtype=np.float, low_memory=False)
```

The result is an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CParserError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-699921ac7a12> in <module>()
----> 1 a=pd.read_csv(loc, skiprows=5+n_coloums+n_rows, header=None, engine='c', low_memory=False, error_bad_lines=False)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, na_fvalues, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
    468                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    469 
--> 470         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    471 
    472     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    254         return parser
    255 
--> 256     return parser.read()
    257 
    258 _parser_defaults = {

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
    713                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
    714 
--> 715         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    716 
    717         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
   1162 
   1163         try:
-> 1164             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1165         except StopIteration:
   1166             if nrows is None:

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7426)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:8377)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:20728)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

Any ideas why and how can I fix this.

**Note**: If I use `engine='python'`, the txt file is loaded normaly.

**Note2**: `error_bad_lines=False` does not change anything.

**Update**
This happens on pandas 0.16.0. On an older version - 0.14.1. it works correctly.

**Update 2**
The bug was fixed in pandas 0.16.1

Comment: same version of pandas on windows and ubuntu?

Comment: Bob, thanks for the comment. I had pandas 0.14.1 installed on ubuntu. When I updated it, the same problem arose.

Comment: Got to be a bug, right?  At least the python engine works

Comment: I moved the issue to: [link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9735)

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7 64-bit python 3.4, pandas 0.16.0

Comment: not work too,  win 7 x64, py2.7 x86, pandas (0.17.1)

Comment: @blaz I think you should post your last update as answer and accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was fixed in pandas 0.16.1